# Can I filter multiple column headers to display subheadings of each in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I can't seem to find this anywhere... it may not even be possible without coding?

I have a spreadsheet containing more than one heading in a single column. These headings are identified with blue background and white font. Each of these headings have items listed below them. These "subheadings" are smaller, auto-black font and no fill background.

Currently I have to scroll down the spreadsheet to view all headers and their contents. How do I create a filter that would allow me to sort on whichever header I want, so that (only) the contents of that particular header are displayed?

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  If Peter’s answer (or any other that has appeared by the time you see this comment) is what you want, that’s wonderful.  But if not, it’s because your question is unclear.  Please **edit your question** to try to explain your problem more clearly.  If you can, post your Excel file (i.e., a minimized copy of it) and/or a screen snapshot of it somewhere on the web, and post the URL here.  Failing that, try representing it as a code (preformatted) block.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Excel 2010, you can use the "Filter by Color" function of the Autofilter:

[image]